# Can the Dinkelbach method solve nonlinear fractional programming problems?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, constraint-programming

Can the Dinkelbach method solve nonlinear fractional programming problems, where the functions in the numerator and denominator are not necessarily quadratic and not convex either?

If not is there a variant or a hybrid version of Dinkelbach's method that caters to these cases?

Comment: Is the numerator convex and the denominator concave/nonnegative, for a minimization problem?

Comment: I'd say non-negative absolutely for sure. Concave would be too much of a specificity to guarantee...

Answer (score 0):

Denote the problem as
$$\min_{x \in X} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
and define:
$$h(\lambda) = \min_{x \in X} \{ f(x)-\lambda g(x) \}$$
When $g(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ in $X$, it is still imminent that $h(\lambda) \leq 0$ if and only if $\min_{x \in X} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \leq \lambda$. The problem now is to find the smallest $\lambda$ such that $h(\lambda) \leq 0$.

Without concavity of $g$, the subproblem for computing $h(\lambda)$ is not convex, so it may be hard to compute $h(\lambda)$. However, the function $h$, being the minimum of functions that are affine in $\lambda$, is still concave. Therefore, it is still straightforward to find the optimal $\lambda$ with, e.g., bisection search.

Comment: I have a lucky situation where I can compute in my case, the $X^*$ where $f(X) -\lambda g(X)$ is minimum even without concavity of $g$. So, from what you say, Dinkelbach algorithm still holds!? Also, kindly elaborate on why bisection search is coming into play? Isnt it different from Dinkelbach's technique? Kindly confirm and elaborate on these. Also, will the solution converge to a global minima in terms of lambda^* and X^* given that my X^* is global minima for any given lambda?

Comment: How would you find the root of $h$?

Comment: I have a special situation for my instances of $f$ and $g$, where I can use a combinatorial algorithm ensuring global minima of h(x)...given a fixed lambda. My question is now...will the dinkelbach's procedure upon convergence of lambda ...ensure that my solution of x is global minima or not?

Comment: Since you repeat yourself: how would you find the root of  $h$?

Comment: what if objective is  
$\max \displaystyle\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{f(x)*g(x)}$